# SEO Category and sub category

Tags: wordpress, seo, categories

I have some issues with my SEO. The goal of the web site I am creating is to display all of my products by category and then by sub-category. My question is: if I display my products in archive category pages and in archive subcategory pages, will google see it duplicate content?
Please excuse me for my English.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as described on the SEO tag wiki, it is an SEO question without a programming component.

Comment: sorry I don't read the description of the tag

Answer (score 0):

Well There is just not a 100% correct answer to that, As no one knows the algorithm google use to indicate a block of a page as duplicate content.

But based on their description on this matter ( Duplicate Content ) on google webmaster support page, This would fall on the duplicate content category.

But as Google’s head of search spam, Matt Cutts, in one of his latest videos on youtube said, he wouldn’t stress about it — that is, unless it is spammy duplicate content. Which means duplicate content would not heart you, unless they are spammy or keyword stuffed.

But, You should definitely steer clear of this problem, and there's a very simple way pf doing that:
If you want google and other search engines to index your website correctly when there are duplicate contents involved, You should use a method that's named conanical links.
( As defined by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) :

> A canonical link element is an HTML element that helps webmasters
>   prevent duplicate content issues by specifying the "canonical" or
>   "preferred" version of a web page as part of search engine
>   optimization. It is described in RFC 6596, which went live in April
>   2012.

)

And the correct way to use the conanical links, are writing them in the page header, and linking to the original page, form which this page is duplicated ( copied ).
This is the correct example :

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://YourDomain.com/The-Original-Page-URL" />
</head>
```

Basically with this method, You are telling the search engines, That this page has the same content as the one mentioned above and you know it, and the original page, which you want the search engines to index, is in the conanical link you mention in the header.
The least dangerous result of duplicate content without conanical links, is that google will only index one the multiple pages they find identical, and they would pick it from the different pages themselves, Which can be different than what you want, because as you said in your question, one of the duplicate pages may be on archive, and as in many content management systems, the archive content doesn't have a very nice looking structure. Which makes you to choose the better structured page as the one you want the search engines to index, and this is the way to let the search engines know which page you choose to be indexed in such situations.

Google Webmaster Support Link Which Address This Same Matter :

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en